# Google Colab Times out

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Trying to find the Jordan form of a given matrix using Colab.
But it always fails or times out.
Not sure why is this failing

```
import numpy as np
import sys
from sympy import Matrix
sys.set_int_max_str_digits(15000)

a = np.array([[1, 2, 4, 8], [1, 3, 9, 27], [1, 4, 16, 64], [1, 5, 25, 125]])
m = Matrix(a)
P, J = m.jordan_form()

J
```

[image: Example Run]

I tried finding Jordan form on Matlab and on online calculators like
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordan+normal+form+calculator
It works fine on these platforms.
Not sure why Colab and Jupyter are not able to compute the Jordan form of the matrix

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Colab and Jupyter are simply environments in which you can run Python codes, and the issue here has nothing to do with using Colab or Jupyter or any IDE.
Secondly, the reason you do not get the results in your example is an algorithmic one. The matrix you are using is ill-conditioned. There is four orders of magnitude difference between the four egnevalues. And the underlying algorithm gets stuck while trying to calculate the Jordan form.
If you try, as an example:

```
a = np.array([[5, 4, 2, 1], [0, 1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, 3, 0], [1, 1, -1, 2]])
```

you will see you code works well and fast.

Comment: So are you suggesting the algorithm python libraries are using is comparatively inefficient to the one which Matlab uses to compute the Jordan form of my matrix?

Comment: I haven't looked into the details of the alogithm in sympy library, but based on the results, it clearly is inefficent. If you calculate eigenvelaues and eignevectors using ´numpy.linalg.eig´, you get them immediately, even for your ill-conditioned matrix. Even its inverse is calculated fast. Maybe calculating the rank causes such an issue. My suggestion is to implement the algorithm yourself, if you have time, or set an "if conditoin" based on eigenvalues to prevent that. This might help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1570526/computing-the-jordan-form-of-a-matrix